# What's wrong with my recursion for the gamblers ruin problem?

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, random-walk, gambling

A gambler has 0 dollars. He tosses a fair coin that gives him 1 dollar on heads and he loses 1 dollar (goes into debt) on tails. What is the probability he'll reach 2 dollars before he goes 1 dollar in debt? I have other means of answering this, but wanted people to look at one particular solution which is returning a nonsense answer.

---

Let's call $P_{i,j}$ the probability that the gambler will hit $i$ dollars before going $j$ dollars in debt. Now, what happens when he tosses the coin once? With $\frac 1 2$ probability he'll make a single dollar and now he has to hit $i-1$ dollars before going $j+1$ dollars in debt. Similarly for if he gets tails he now has to hit $i+1$ dollars before going $j-1$ dollars in debt. So we get the recurrence:

$$P_{i,j} = \frac{1}{2} P_{i+1,j-1} + \frac{1}{2} P_{i-1,j+1}$$

Now plug in $i=2$ and $j=1$. We get:

$$P_{2,1} = \frac{1}{2} P_{3,0} + \frac{1}{2} P_{1,2} \tag{1}$$

Now we should have $P_{3,0}=0$ (which is another way of saying that if he gets tails he's already lost). Also, by symmetry we should have: $P_{1,2}=P_{2,1}$. But combining these two facts gives us:

$$P_{2,1}=0$$

What went wrong here?

Comment: Gambler's ruin generally refers to a problem that ends when the gambler has $0$ dollars (i.e. "ruin").  Are you referring instead to the symmetric random walk on the integers?

Comment: Sure, we can think of it as a slightly modified gamblers ruin problem but symmetric random walk might be more apt.

Comment: Are you sure about the symmetry $P_{1,2}=P_{2,1}$?

Comment: You're right. That is the hole probably.

Comment: You're right there is a symmetry, but it should be $P_{1,2}=1-P_{2,1}$.

Comment: $P_{2,1}=\frac{1}{2}P_{1,2}\implies 1-P_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}P_{1,2}\implies1=\frac{3}{2}P_{1,2}\implies P_{1,2}=\frac{2}{3}.$

Comment: That solves it. You can copy paste your comments into an answer if you like. If you're feeling lazy, I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right there is a symmetry, but it should be $P_{1,2}=1-P_{2,1}$.

This is because those are the only two stopping conditions. He either reaches $2$ dollars before reaching $1$ dollar and if not, he must have reached $1$ dollar before he reached $2$ dollars.